# RDP vs Console session

Tags: rdp

When I log in with a console session I have the normal standard Ubuntu 22 desktop.

When logging in using RDP (xrdp installed) I get a different desktop experience.

How do I get the standard console style desktop over RDP ?

EDIT: When trying the suggested answer I am unable to move forward from xorg after selecting "Local Active Session" with Username / Password defined. Clicking OK does nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local ubuntu desktop cannot login after logging in remotely via Xrdp session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326143/local-ubuntu-desktop-cannot-login-after-logging-in-remotely-via-xrdp-session)

Comment: No, this doesn't help. I am able to login locally as well as remotely no problem but not at the same time. It's just that when remotely I get a variation in desktop experience. For example RMB doesn't give me all the options as when logging in locally.

Comment: I also get the following when following the link provided @raffa:                    root@t-box:~# gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
No such schema “org.gnome.Vino”

Comment: Login as a normal user **not** `root` and `gsettings …` will work … It’s generally not advisable to login as `root` and especially on the DE and particularly remotely.

Comment: I only log in as a normal user. The above was run under root context (sudo -i)

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false

Comment: No such schema “org.gnome.Vino”

Comment: Xrdp will always start a new session that is different from the local session unless you follow the workaround in the linked post above then you will get the same experience AFAIK.

Comment: Did you enable screen sharing and set a password for it first?

Comment: Will check again - Another thing I notice is that when I open a fresh RDP session following a reboot I need to click on shortcuts twice (e.g. Tilda) to get the app to run.

Comment: If that isn’t resolved after trying the workaround in the linked post, then please add it with as much other details to your question and clarify it to get better help responces from the community

Comment: @Raffa - working through the workaround again I suspect I wasn't actually chasing anything via my RDP session from my Mac MS Remote Desktop session. Now I am in the XRDP session and I can drop down to the newly defined "Local Active Session".

Comment: Does the legacy option need to be enabled for Desktop Sharing ?

Comment: Also the xrdp.ini edit mentions lib=libvnc.so - does this still apply when going over Xrdp ?

Comment: Last time I checked this was more than a year and a half ago  … I did it with a virtual machine for the sole purpose of helping the asker in that linked post … Otherwise never checked again but as for `libvnc.so` I guess still required … Disabling encryption however might be ignored if your client can handle it.

Comment: Just a note … `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false` is run as your normal user that you login with both locally and remotely  i.e. **not** with `sudo` **nor** with `sudo -i`

Comment: Please see the [comments here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448037/use-gnome-remote-desktop-before-the-very-first-login#comment2528242_1448043) ... You are right that command for disabling encryption worked for the old Vino server ... For the new VNC server in 22.04 , encryption is disabled by setting empty password for the login item in the keyring app.

Comment: I updated [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1326144/968501) in the previously linked post as well .. I hope it helps.