# How to logout local user after the same user entering as xrdp session?

Tags: xrdp

Windows RDP session logout local user, everybody knows.
But Linux xrdp creates a new session, but local session still exists. I need to logout a local session when the same user entering as xrdp.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1326144

Comment: Thank you, but I'm thinking about your solution. It is not the same as I wanted.

Comment: I found solution to connect an existing session even on logon screen, rdp -> vnc.