# Remote Desktop - connect to existing local logged-in session (:0)

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have a remote desktop setup on Ubuntu similar to what happens with the Windows Remote Desktop.  I've seen a lot of tutorials and Q&As that talk about starting a *new* remote session and attaching to that, but I haven't found anything that would allow me to connect to an *existing* logged-in session.

I've tried using tigerVNC, but in order to use that, I have to close down all of my applications first, log off, then start a new X11 session with the VNC server, which the laptop connects to.  When I return to the physical computer, I need to kill the VNC server (and all the applications running) before I can log back in.

Maybe this is clearer to explain by example.  Here's what I would sometimes do with the Windows built-in remote desktop:

- On computer A, I sit down at the physical mouse/keyboard/monitor and log in.  I launch some applications and start working.  Computer A has dual monitors.
- Later in the day, I need to relocate.  I grab laptop B and go to my new location.  From laptop B, I start a remote desktop connection to computer A.  I am then presented with my open applications that were running when I left the physical mouse/keyboard/monitor of computer A.  Laptop B has only one monitor, of a different resolution than the computer A monitors.  The remote desktop session has resized the desktop to match the resolution of laptop B.
- Later on, I return to the physical location of computer A.  I disconnect laptop B, sit down at computer A, and log back in.  I am presented with the applications exactly as I left them on laptop B, and the desktop session again spans my 2 monitors.

Is there any Linux software available which would let me accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local ubuntu desktop cannot login after logging in remotely via Xrdp session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326143/local-ubuntu-desktop-cannot-login-after-logging-in-remotely-via-xrdp-session)

Comment: @Raffa I tried those suggestions, but I could not get vino (or its replacement, gnome-remote-desktop-daemon) to work.

Comment: It might be an encryption thing … have you tried to disable encryption? … It’s mentioned in the linked post.