# Gnome and xrdp session black screen -- automatic way to log out stale session?

Tags: gnome, xrdp, session

Using Ubuntu 20.04.

XRDP using GNOME is causing problems. Users close their RDP sessions but they dont seem to disconnect properly. This causes the issue of the user seeing a black screen after login.

I followed [this workaround](http://catch22cats.blogspot.com/2018/05/xrdp-blank-screen-with-ubuntu-1804.html) but this seems like a bad idea as it will just keep creating new sessions, right?

Is there a way to automatically log out stale sessions or remove it for a user when they login, and create a new session for them?

I have a feeling the solution is "Dont use gnome for xrdp use xfce", is that true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local Ubuntu desktop cannot login after opened Xrdp session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054063/local-ubuntu-desktop-cannot-login-after-opened-xrdp-session)

Comment: Nope, it sure does not.

Comment: Are you using Wayland in your remote desktop by any chance? Try [switching from Wayland to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).